# Parsing command line arguments as strings to store integer in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I am following a Fortran tutorial, however the below code does not seem to work. I am trying to read a 2 digit number from command line, however I get the error UNIT specification at "TRIM(buffer)" must be an INTEGER expression or a CHARACTER variable.

```
INTEGER :: number
CHARACTER(LEN=20) :: buffer

buffer = ""
CALL GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(1, buffer)
READ(TRIM(buffer), FMT="(I2)") number
```

So the issue as I understand it, is that READ is not sure that the output of TRIM will return a CHARACTER value. Can I somehow declare that it is a CHARACTER or is there another way of getting around this issue?

For what it is worth I am using gfortran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TRIM(buffer)` indeed returns a character value.  This is, however, an *expression* and not a *variable*.  As the error message suggests, an expression is fine for giving a unit number, but in the case of reading from a character, a variable is required.

As `TRIM` will act merely to provide a value with the trailing spaces stripped from `buffer`, this isn't needed: the spaces won't affect the reading.  Instead, just go for

```
read(buffer, '(I2)') number
```

or even

```
read(buffer(1:2), '(I2)') number
```

More generally, a more complicated character expression can be assigned to a variable and this latter variable used in the read context.